# Batch File Transfer addon

Tags: batch

I made a Batch file that allows me to move files to one hard drive to the next hard drive.  There is just one thing I would like to add to it. I want the CMD to prompt me to what user account its going to.

Example:
xcopy /s/z D:\"Documents and Settings"\%username%\Desktop C:\Users\USER\Desktop

Where is says "USER" need to add the user account to which one its going to.
Example.
xcopy /s/z D:\"Documents and Settings"\%username%\Desktop C:\Users\Dang\Desktop

So What I am looking for is when i Start the .Bat file it will ask me what "User account" would you like to transfer the data to? Than I would be able to add the name I want in there.

Answer (score 4):

You can prompt the user to enter a string with the /p-flag on the set command, e.g.:

```
set /p targetuser="Enter target username: "
xcopy /s/z "D:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop" "C:\Users\%targetuser%\Desktop"
```

For use in scripting, it is often beneficial to avoid halting for user input. The following line would use the first parameter supplied to your batch file instead and execute without interruptions:

```
xcopy /s/z "D:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop" "C:\Users\%~1\Desktop"
```

Comment: Why did you add a ~? to the second script?

Comment: As documented [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true), the tilde is a modifier that strips surrounding quotes off the parameter. That way, the script will not break under either `copy.bat Daniel Doe` or `copy.bat "Daniel Doe"`.

Comment: This worked! :)

set /p targetuser="Enter target username: "
xcopy /s/z "D:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop" "C:\Users\%targetuser%\Desktop"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with a command line parameter:

```
xcopy /s/z D:\"Documents and Settings"\%username%\Desktop C:\Users\%1\Desktop
```

Then run the script like so:

```
C:>sciptname.bat username
```

Comment: Well I dont want to change the D Drive Username. I want to change the one going to the C Drive.

Comment: I tried doing the scriptname.bat Username but it makes it unusable

Comment: I've edited the script to reflect your comment.

Comment: Could you please expand on "makes it unusable"?